# Characterization of convergence of measures.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Recently reading the Marcelo Vianna's Book, Foundations of Ergodic Theory, I came across to the following:

Let be $M$ a metric space, we have the following characterization of convergence of sequence of borelian measures  in $M$ with respect to  the  weak topology:
$$
\mu_n\to \mu \iff \int f d\mu_n\to \int fd\mu,  \forall~ f\in C_b(M)
$$
where $C_b(M)$ means the set of all bounded continuous functions.

It is that correct? For a compact $M$ I know this is correct but for non compact $M$ I think this is false...  Can anyone provide me a clarification

**Edit:** In order to clarify my question, $\mathcal{M}$ means the set of all Borelians finite measures in $M$, and the weak topology that I am talking about is the topology generated by the functionals  $\varphi_{\mu}$
 of  the form 
$$
\varphi_{\mu}:\mathcal{M} \ni \mu \mapsto \int f d\mu \in \mathbb{R}
$$
where $f\in C_{b}(M)$.

Comment: Is this weak convergence of measures? Are these finite measures?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about convergence in the weak topology. And yes I am considering finite measures.

Comment: What is the definition of weak convergence you are using? The equivalence you have stated is usually the definition of weak convergence for finite, not necessarily probability, measures.

Comment: I am considering the topology in $\mathcal{M}$ generated by the all functionals  $\varphi_{f}: \mathcal{M}\ni \mu\mapsto \int f d\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $f\in C_b(M)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu_n(M)=\mu(M)<\infty$ for all $n$, then the assertion is true (in both directions), since these are essentially probability measures. $M$ does not have to be compact. See the [Portmanteau Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures).